# Why Lord Krishna says he is Bhrigu in sages?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

Why Lord Krishna says he is Bhrigu in sages whereas Bhrigu rishi put leg on the Lord Vishnu's chest? Is there any reason behind calling himself as Sage bhrigu?

reference [geeta ch-10 verse 25](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-10-23.html)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prabhupāda [notes](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/10/25) that Bhṛgu is the most powerful among all of Brahmā's sons, so that's why Kṛṣṇa says he's Bhṛgu among the ṛṣi's in [BG 10.25](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/10/25):

> Brahmā, the ﬁrst living creature within the universe, created several sons for the propagation of various kinds of species. Among these sons, Bhṛgu is the most powerful sage ...

Also, [according to](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01006.htm) the Mahābhārata, Bhṛgu was also reborn out of fire:

> The great and blessed saint Bhrigu, we are informed, was produced by the self-existing Brahma **from the fire** at the sacrifice of Varuna.

And a couple of verses earlier ([BG 10.23](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/10/23)), we see that Kṛṣṇa is comparing himself with fire (Agni).

> Of all the Rudras I am Lord Śiva, of the Yakṣas and Rākṣasas I am the Lord of wealth [Kuvera], **of the Vasus I am ﬁre** [**Agni**], and of mountains I am Meru.